# No resource-id element in UIautomatorviewer.bat

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

i'm trying to automate a app to do everything that you would have to do by hand. My main goal right now is to get it to type my email in the "Enter your email address" field.

But I've ran into a bump while trying to find the resource-id element in uiautomatorviewer.bat

There is no text in the resource-id field.
[image]

Is there anyway to get around this? How else could I find the element to plug into my

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/")).sendKeys("xxxxxx@gmail.com");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xpath for this

```
By path = By.Xpath("//*[@text='Enter your email address']");
driver.findElement(path).sendKeys("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this to find `text` based on `classname` and then perform `sendKeys`

```
List<WebElement> offerElements= 
   driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));

for (int i=0;i<offerElements.size();i++) {
 if (offerElements.get(i).getText().equals("Enter your email address"))
    offerElements.get(i).sendKeys("email text");
}
```

Comment: When I put this in my IDE, **List gets underlined red.** If I import java.util or java.awt, **driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));** then gets underlined red.

Comment: @DamoneWilliams - sorry method name was `findElements` and I have used `findElement`. I have updated the code now. `import` should be `java.util`

Answer (score 0):

You xpath aa follows

`//android.widget.EditText[@text='Enter your email address']`

And use `sendKeys()`  for what ever you need to use.